# Ascertaining a shutdown is closing my application

Tags: c#, .net, shutdown

Is it possible in .NET to ascertain whether my application is closing due to Windows being given a shutdown command (as opposed to any old application closing) in order to either write out some temporary cache files or even block the shutdown long enough to prompt for user input?

Whilst my current scope involves a Winform app and a windows service, I am interested in understanding this in a generic way if possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SystemEvents.SessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) looks like a good starting point for you. That article talks about the event sequence involved when a logout/shutdown is occurring.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you will want to handle the [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(VS.85).aspx) Windows message. This will give your application a chance to do cleanup, or to block the shutdown if it's really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the SessionEnded event on the Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents type.