# Application 'Deactivate' event

Tags: winforms

I'm looking for something similar with 'Form.Deactivate' event but per application. If I use Form.Deactivate event on my MainForm this event is fired even when I open a modal dialog that has as parent my MainForm.

In conclusion I nedd an event that is fired when my application was deactivated.

Comment: What are you going to do in response to this condition?

Comment: This [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245111/ascertaining-a-shutdown-is-closing-my-application) should provide a good starting point.

Comment: I'll start watching some folders using 'FileSystemWatcher' component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an odd omission but easily fixed.  Paste this in your startup form:

```
protected void OnActivateApp(bool activate) {
  Console.WriteLine("Activate {0}", activate);
}
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  // Trap WM_ACTIVATEAPP
  if (m.Msg == 0x1c) OnActivateApp(m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero);
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: I think that there is win32 bug in this case. If I minimize my application by clicking on the taskbar (my application) the app seems to still be activated. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: That works fine when I try it.  Make sure there is actually another app that can get the focus.  Use the Resize event to inspect WindowState to detect the user minimizing the window.