# Textbox's autocomplete in WebBrowser fires Deactivate event of the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox, browser

I have a Windows `Form` which contains a `WebBrowser` to display webpages. Whenever the user presses outside the `Form`, the `Form`'s "`Deactivate`" event is fired, which I handle by calling `Form.Close()` to have the behavior of closing the `Form` whenever the user clicks outside it.

This works great for some webpages, but unfortunately other webpages sometimes contain an HTML `TextBox` which has the property of "`autocomplete`" set to `true`. Whenever the user starts typing in the webpage (in the WebBrowser component), the `TextBox` starts suggesting texts for the user.

The main problem is that when the user clicks any text from the suggestions the "`Deactivate`" event of the Form is fired **!!!** So the `Form` is unfortunately closed, which is a behavior I don't want it to happen.

How to solve this issue ? I want that the `Form` closes only when uses clicks outside it, and not to close when the user clicks an autocomplete suggestion inside the WebBrowser ?

How could I, for example, detect that the event is caused by clicking a suggestion so that I may cancel the event's handler ? Or is there another solution to prevent calling "`Deactivate`" on suggestion clicking ? Or does another solution exist ?

BTW, I'm using `Form.Show()`, not `Form.ShowDialog()`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be something else going on besides just selecting from the textbox - like using a [Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747562/application-deactivate-event)

I tried following code and Deactivate was not triggered when I selected one of the suggestions.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.Deactivate += Form1_Deactivate;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection acsc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        {
                "Jan", "Feb", "March"
        };
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acsc;

 }
```

Comment: As I see, you created a textbox in the form itself. But That's not the case. I've a form containing a webbrowser component and the webbrowser URL is set to display a page (a normal HTML page of any website) and the HTML textbox has the autocomplete property set to true. Then if you select from this HTML textbox component in the webbrowser component using the mouse click, it'll fire the form deactivate trigger.

Comment: Ok. Did you try the solution in link in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747562/application-deactivate-event)

Comment: I'll give it a try and flush you back with the results, thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately the link didn't help, especially that I have to use "Show" not "ShowDialog" to have the behavior of closing when the user clicks outside the forml. PS, using ShowDialog, it's not possible to click outside it. Any other suggestions ?